# How to build a WebGrid with editable checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

I want to build an WebGrid with editable checkbox on some fields. I´m trying with no success:

```
@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 25, canPage: true, canSort: true, defaultSort: "GroupName");
 }

@grid.Pager();

@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "gridTable", headerStyle: "gridHead", footerStyle: "gridFooter", alternatingRowStyle: "gridAltRow", selectedRowStyle: "gridSelRow", rowStyle: "gridRow",
columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("GroupName", "GROUP", canSort: true),
    grid.Column("ScreenName", "SCREEN", canSort: true),
    grid.Column("CanDelete", "DELETE", canSort: true, format: @<text>@Html.EditorForModel(item.CanDelete)</text>))
))
```

My ViewModel has:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public stirng GroupName { get; set; }
    public string ScreenName {get; set; }
    public bool CanDelete { get; set; }
}
```

Using this configuration , I´m getting CS1973 Error at View:

rid.Column("CanDelete", "DELETE", canSort: true, format: @@Html.EditorForModel(item.CanDelete)))

But I have tried several changes with no success.

My goal is to allow user to change Delete checkbox and than save it on db.

Thanks,